# How to generate jssecacerts file in java 7

Tags: java, jboss, centos, jms

I have developed an enterprise application which has an independant module for sending mails. For this purpose I have used Java Messaging Services(JMS). And I have used ActiveMQ for message broker services.

Kindly appreciate if anyone could mention URLs of the tutorials which contains step by step process to create and configure jssecacerts file for above purpose.

Server environment is listed below.

Java version: 7
Operating system: CentOS 5.9 server
Application server: JBoss 6 M2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keytool utility to

1. Generate a cert in a keystore
2. Export the cert out from that keystore
3. Optional: Sign the certificate with a CA
4. Add the cert to a truststore

Examples here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ablqz.html#ghlgv

Finally, you would tell your application to use the cert like so:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","<location of trustStore>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<password>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","<location of keyStore>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","<password>");
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny.

When I tried the certificate generating method mentioned in that URL of your post, I got InvalidAlgorithmParameterException. (Below shown is the log entry of the exception message in my app)

"DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

I generated the jks file and added into jre/lib/security folder.

Appreciate your response on this.

Comment: This most likely means the jks file was not found. What is the location you specified? This is sometimes tricky especially if using relative paths. Perhaps you can try hardcode the absolute path.